# Hide/show DIV on SELECT change

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to show/hide a `div` element on `select` change depending on values. For that I do this:

```
$("#form_pdetail").on("click", "#prod_detail_create_field_type", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 1 || $(this).val() == 2 || $(this).val() == 3) {
        $("#values").removeAttr("display");
    } else {
        $("#values").attr("style", "display: none");
    }
});
```

But it's not working since `div#values` never show up. What I'm doing wrong? Should I use `toggle()` instead?

Comment: Rather than `$(this)`, try using `$("#theIdOfYourSelectBox")`.

Comment: Also, rather than using `attr` and `removeAttr`, simply use `show` and `hide` - `$("#values").show()` for example.

Comment: $("#values").removeAttr("display");   the problem with this is `display` is part of the style attribute.   so there is no display attribute...

Comment: @Grim... thanks both suggestions works

Comment: No worries. I'll add it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `toggle()`

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide

```
var val = parseInt($(this).val());
$("#values").toggle(val == 1 || val == 2 || val == 3);
```

---

if `prod_detail_create_field_type` is a `select` element, you'll want to use `change`, not `click`.

if `prod_detail_create_field_type` is actually the `name` of `radio` `input` elements you'll want to bind your event to `[name='prod_detail_create_field_type']`

Comment: Is `prod_detail_create_field_type` a bunch of radio buttons?

Answer (score 2):

Use `css` instead of the `attr` functionality:

`$("#values").css({'display': 'block'});` or `$("#values").css({'display': 'none'});`.

As a shortcut, you can use `.hide()` and `.show()`

Comment: are you sure?  looks like he's delegating the event to `#prod_detail_create_field_type`, which may be his `select`.  It's hard to tell.  It is clear what is wrong though: the use of `attr`.

Comment: Quite right - do I ever need to shut up ;-) Pretty sure there needs to be some `parseInt` action in there, too.

Comment: maybe, does "1" == 1?  I'm sure there's a stackoverflow question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `$(this)`, try using `$("#theIdOfYourSelectBox")`

Also, rather than using `attr` and `removeAttr`, simply use `show` and `hide` - `$("#values").show()` for example.

Finally, the values you should be comparing may need to be `"1"` and `"2"` in quotes (unless you parse the val() to an int).